# Drawing a rectangle using 2 coordinates that may not be in the correct order

Tags: php

I am given 2 coordinates and need to draw a rectangle. The problem I am having is that, sometimes the coordinates are top right an bottom left. When I use these coordinated it draws a "mirrored" rectangle. How do I know when I am getting top right and bottom left coordinates and then how do I "flip" those coordinates to draw a rectangle in the correct place?
 The first illustration is when I get coordinates that start top right and go to bottom right. The second illustration is when I get coordinates starting top left and bottom right.

```
     ___________
    /|          |
   / |          |
  /  |          |
 /   |__________|

______
|\    |
|  \  |
|   \ |
|____\|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to divide the coordinates up into separate x and y values representing each line of the rectangle and then put them back together into new points representing the corners.

Pseudo code:

```
function normalise(p1, p2):
    let x1 = p1.x
    let x2 = p2.x
    let y1 = p1.y
    let y2 = p2.y

    let topLeft = Point(min(x1, x2), min(y1, y2))
    let bottomRight = Point(max(x1, x2), max(y1, y2))

    return (topLeft, bottomRight)
```

This pseudo code assumes that (0,0) is the top left corner of the drawing area (as is common in 2D computer graphics).

Comment: Well, it's better than my pseudocode, have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion that means you don't need to worry about that.

If your points are `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` then the following points are at the corners of the rectange, irrespective of the whether or not you've provided the top left and bottom right, or the top right and bottom left corners:

```
(max(x1, x2), max(y1, y2))
(max(x1, x2), min(y1, y2))
(min(x1, x2), max(y1, y2))
(min(x1, x2), min(y1, y2))
```